# Finding maximum value in a group using proc means in SAS?

Tags: sas

Suppose i have data like this in my table

```
match_day name    Goals

1         Higuain   4 
1         Messi     1
1         Ozil      4
1         Villa     3
1         Xavi      4
2        Benzema    4
2        Messi      4
2        Ronaldo    3
2         Villa     4
2         Xavi      4
```

Now i want to find out which player scored the maximum goals in each match. I tried using it doing-

```
  proc means data=b nway max;
  class match_day name;
  var goals;
  output out=c(drop=_type_ _freq_) max=goals;
  run;
```

But this does not work. What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Because the second column is Player, not name...

Comment: oh no ..it is name only..my bad...editing

Comment: What does the log tell you and/or what output do you get, if any?

Comment: this would be extremely simple using proc sql if you're open to that.

Comment: yeah i know..but i do not want to use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't something you can easily do in PROC MEANS.  It's much easier to do in SQL or the data step.  The most direct solution:

```
proc sort data=b;
by match_day descending goals; *so the highest goal number is at top;
run; 

data c;
set b;
by match_day;
if first.match_day; *the first record per match_day;
run;
```

That will give you the record with the largest number of goals.  If there is a tie, you will not get more than one record, but instead arbitrarily the first.

If you want to keep all records with that number, you can do:

```
data c;
set b;
retain keep;
by match_day descending goals;
if first.match_day then keep=1; *the first record per match_day, flag to keep;
if keep=1 then output;          *output records to be kept;
if last.goals then keep=0;      *clear the keep flag at the end of the first goals set;
drop keep;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to clear up the PROC MEANS syntax, you could use the following code to show the top goal scorer per match_day.

```
proc means data=b noprint nway;
class match_day;
output out=c(drop=_:) maxid(goals(name goals))=;
run;
```

However, you get the issue raised by @Joe that only one record per match_day is returned, which isn't ideal in this situation where there are ties for top scorer.

If you wanted to use a procedure, then PROC RANK can do this for you.

```
proc rank data=b out=c (where=(goals_rank=1)) ties=low descending;
by match_day;
var goals;
ranks goals_rank;
run;
```